# is SpelExpression thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, spring, spring-el

Specifically, can getValue(StandardEvaluationContext, Class) safely be called from multiple threads on the same SpelExpression with different contexts?

I saw this question asked and answered by Gary Russell from Spring Source.  However, I also see people reporting concurrency issues.  I looked through the source code of related Spring classes and I can't be sure.

I would like to get a definite answer from Spring developers who've worked with spring-el or from Spring users who've used this class in heavily concurrent environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I know you want another opinion, but I will clarify that it is thread-safe as long as you don't mutate the evaluation context while it's being used by another thread (or you use a new evaluation context each time, if you need to customize it with variables etc),

However, you must pass the root object into the getValue() rather than setting the root object on the context (using `setRootObject()` - which would mutate the context). If you have a `#root` object, use

```
getValue(EvaluationContext context, Object rootObject, Class<T> expectedResultType)
```

If you don't have a root object, and don't otherwise mutate the context, it's ok to use

```
getValue(EvaluationContext context, Class<T> expectedResultType)
```

with a shared context.

Spring Integration uses SpEL extensively in (in many cases) a highly multi-threaded environment. We use the same evaluation context for all static cases (no runtime variables) and pass the root object (message, usually) into the `getValue()` call. For cases where we need to add variables to the context, each evaluation gets a new evaluation context.

Comment: Thanks for the assurance, Gary.  This is what we're doing.  

`
    private Expression exp = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("#msg['direction']=='BUY'");

    // hope the above Expression is thread-safe as used by the following method.
    //
    public boolean pass(Map<String,Object> message) {
        StandardEvaluationContext context = new   StandardEvaluationContext();
        context.setVariable("msg", message);

        return exp.getValue(context, Boolean.class);
    }

Comment: Yes, that's fine because you create a new evaluation context each time. However since you only have one variable `msg`, you could use a shared context and use `['direction']=='BUY'` (with `msg` being the `#root` object. `getValue(context, msg, Boolean.class)`.

Comment: Thanks, Gary.  I learned a lot from you.  I now cache EvaluationContext and Expression and use exp.getValue(context, msg, Boolean.class).